# how to edit json attribute without manipulating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, loops, state

say I have a json object like so called student :

```
{id: 1, 
 name: jon,
 hobbies:[running, basketball, soccer]
}
```

Without mutating state, I want to edit the hobbies array so that each element is a `Hobby` model. So basically iterate through each element in `student.hobbies` and call `new Hobby(element)` on each element. How can I do this without mutating state?

Comment: use a ref - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Comment: Is it something coming from a `useState()` hook? If yes I don't think there is a way to change without mutating coz these words are synonymous. Maybe before you pass it to useState

Comment: Yeah, if you don't need your component to rerender when this obj changes, you can use `ref.current` to save this object to and it will be preserved between component renders

Comment: how would using `ref.current` work

Answer (score 1):

You can `map()` over the hobbies and use each value to create a `Hobby` object, code could look something like this.

```
const [student, setStudent] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("url").then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    // imagine data is { id: 1, name: "jon", hobbies: ["running", "basketball", "soccer"] }
    setStudent({
      ...data,
      hobbies: data.hobbies.map(h => new Hobby(h))
    });
  });  
}, []);
```